# требуется обновить wordpress до 4.6

Tags: wordpress

Стал делать settings gogle analitics и потребовала:

> MonsterInsights requires WordPress version 4.6 or newer to use oAuth. Please update your WordPress version.

У меня  в админке:   стоит wp 4.0

Читаю в админке :

> последний раз проверено 31 Июль 2017 в 12:10   Проверить еще раз
>   У вас установлена самая свежая версия WordPress. Будущие обновления безопасности будут применяться автоматически.

Вот не могу понять фразу - стоит самая свежая версия WP.

Можете объяснить?

Comment: В wp-config.php есть строка вида `define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', ...... );`? Что в ней?

Answer (score 1):

> стоит самая свежая версия WP

4,0. [далеко не свежая](https://ru.wordpress.org/releases/). Видимо стоит какая-то сборка, со своими серверами обновлениями, которая не обновлялась 3 года.  Нужно обновить на родной ВП.
Причем с такой древней лучше делать последовательно - через все ключевые ветки - 4.0.18, 4.1.18, .. и до 4.8.1 которая выйдет не сегодня-завтра ;)

Не забыть обновить плагины. При отсутствии оных  в [оф каталоге](https://wordpress.org/plugins/) (или древних) лучше избавиться от них (заменить на актуальные при необходимости).
Тему тоже лучше сменить на современную, безопасную из [оф. каталога](https://wordpress.org/themes/).

https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_WordPress_Lecactus_Edition

https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%83_MyWordPress.ru